# Meaning of けらている

Tags: meaning, kanji, song-lyrics

From a song: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5T-L0b43no

Bolded parts are what I'm struggling with with.

> あたしは目を瞑って静かに座っているのに
>
> なぜかの**けらている**ようなそんな**浮遊感**だ

It looks like 浮遊感 means "floating/drifting feeling", as in floating in the air. But what is けらている? I can't figure out what it's meant to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's なぜか ("somehow", "for some reason") + [退け【のけ】](https://jisho.org/word/%E9%80%80%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B-1)られている ("to be being shunned/alienated"). 浮遊感 literally means "floating/drifting feeling", but in this context it symbolizes her sense of detachment from other people in the class.